# Passwordless auth for WinRM

Tags: linux, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, windows-server-2016, winrm

I need to connect to a list of windows servers and update certificates from a certificate host.

The certificate host is running certbot on linux.  All hosts are connected to the domain and the linux host has machine certificates from the ADCS server.

I would like to use WinRM to do this with PowerShell.  Is it possible to configure passwordless login with certificates / AD groups / or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Remote Management supports "passwordless" authentication methods via Client Certificate-based Authentication.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/authentication-for-remote-connections
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management